# Removed Crashlytics still getting Crashlytics error on build

Tags: firebase, flutter, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I removed the Firebase Crashlytics library and references from my Flutter project but I still get this error:

```
Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing.
```

Everytime I build my project I get the above error in my build log. All references to Crashlytics were removed from both the project app gradle file and module gradle file, the library dependency was removed from my yaml file. I ran flutter clean and also restarted Android studio, but I still get that Crashlytics error in my build log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebaser here - If this error still exists, it's likely that there is still a reference to Crashlytics somewhere in your app code or dependencies. Since it's looking for the InitProvider, it could be that you still have some app code that is referencing Firebase or Crashlytics. Perhaps a call to a Crashlytics API in a file somewhere? In Android Studio, you could use CMD+shift+F and search for "Firebase" or "Crashlytics" to find any references still hanging around.

Comment: In addition, run `flutter clean`

Comment: I didn't find any references to Crashlytics, lots to Firebase because I'm using Firestore, Auth, Core and Analytics. Also already ran flutter clean. Same error. Looks like a cache issue somewhere, but not sure.

Comment: @Kevin I should also add that I orinigally tried using apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' but changed it to apply plugin: 'io.fabric' since that is what is listed for the flutter plugin here: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics would this cause issues?

Answer (score 0):

In your `[project]/android/build.gradle` file remove the fabric repo and it's classpath

```
repositories {
  google()
  jcenter()

  // remove the following
  maven {
    url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
  }

}

dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'

  // remove the following
  classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
}
```

In your `[project]/android/app/build.gradle` file, remove the fabric plugin

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric' // remove this
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' //leave this
```

And then run `flutter clean`

Comment: Hmm... could you ensure that the plugin removed in the app level `build.gradle`